# JQuery / JSON dropdown box population

Tags: jquery, json

Back to populating HTML drop down boxes.

I have a php file (dropdown.php) producing an output in JSON;

```
{ "filenames" : [ "xml_cd.xml", "xml_plants.xml" ] }
```

I'm now trying to have JQuery generate a dropdown box with those as options within it.

Here's the HTML.

```
<body>

<script>

var obj;

function setupTableNamesList()
{
  $.getJSON ("dropdown.php",
    function(jsondata) {
      if ( jsondata.names.length > 0 )
      {
        var html = '<select id="tablename" name="tablename">';
        html += '<option value="none">Please select a table</option>';
        for ( i = 0; i < jsondata.filenames.length; i++ )
        html += '<option value="' + jsondata.filenames[i] +'">' + jsondata.filenames[i] + '</option>';
        html += "</select>";
        $("#select xml").html(html);
      }

    }//function
  );

}//setupTableNamesList

$(document).ready(function(){

  setupTableNamesList();  

});//$(document).ready




</script>

    <form>
<div id ="test">

</div>
        <div id ="select xml">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm not receiving any kind of error, but the drop down box isn't appearing either - a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

EDIT * The php script

```
<?php


$dir = glob("xml/*.xml");
$count = count($dir);
$json = '{ "filenames" : [ ';
        $j = 0;

if ($count > 0)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        $j++;
        if ($j > 1)
        {
            $json .=  ', ';
        }
        $name = (substr($dir[$i],4));
        $json .= '"' . $name . '"';

    }

    $json .= ' ] } ';
    echo ($json);
    }
else
{
    echo "error";
}   

?>
```

Comment: I would first look at: `id="select xml"`.  jQuery selector will not like that.  Try making the ID just be `selectxml`.   Make sure you update where you reference in jQuery selector too.

Comment: can you get jsondata.filenames.length ? is it > 0? palce an alert

Comment: I've tried to change the ID to have no spaces, made no difference at all.

@Dibu - Now that you mention it, I'm not able to have an alert box run after the If .lenth either!

Comment: Can you show us the .php file content? Are you setting the header content type correctly using `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: @JamieDunstan I've editing the post to include the php file.

Answer (score 1):

`jsondata.names.length > 0` should be `jsondata.filenames.length > 0`. Even better would be:

```
if (jsondata && jsondata.filenames && jsondata.filenames.length > 0)
```

This will prevent your app from erroring out in case you are not getting what you expect.

Comment: I copy pasted an older snippet! That had since been corrected - I have added the If (thank you for that!) However the function still don't seem to run!

Answer (score 0):

A basic version of your JavaScript implementation seems to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {

    var jsondata = { "filenames" : [ "xml_cd.xml", "xml_plants.xml" ] }

    if ( jsondata.filenames.length > 0 )
    {
        var html = '<select id="tablename" name="tablename">';
        html += '<option value="none">Please select a table</option>';
        for ( i = 0; i < jsondata.filenames.length; i++ )
            html += '<option value="' + jsondata.filenames[i] +'">' + jsondata.filenames[i] + '</option>';
        html += "</select>";

        jQuery("#selectxml").html(html);
    }

});
```

Note, that I have replaced **jsondata.names** with **jsondata.filenames** and I have renamed the ID of your element from **select xml** to **selectxml**.

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qwe4n/).

That being the case, I'm assuming that the issue lies in the php. I would strongly recommend setting the header correctly in the php. Here's a really basic example:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = '{ "filenames" : [ "xml_cd.xml", "xml_plants.xml" ] }';
echo $json;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ( jsondata.names.length > 0 )`

Whoops...